# Actionscript3 when time is up go to another function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I dont't know about flash but want to make little animation. I have clock running at the moment and when time is up I want animation to go and do another function. That function has:

`private function proceed(signal:Event):void` so it should start after time function gives command.
How do I command it to go to that function in time function?

```
private function time(signal:Event):void
        {
            var moment:Date = new Date();
            var time:Number =(moment.getTime() - this.startingmiment.getTime())/1000;
            time_txt.text = String(time);
            if (time> 20){
                proceed();
            }
```

EDIT:

I dont know how to use setTimeout  or it doesnt work, even there is example on that page. 
errors:
call to possibly undefined method setTimeout; 
access of possibly undefined property proceed through a reference with static type game.  definition flash:utils could not be found.

I have private functions all and i refer to everything with prefix "this." so i wrote

```
public function SetTimeoutExample() {
        var intervalId:uint = setTimeout(this.proceed, this.delay);     
    }
```

delay was also given value at the start of program. I dont get what intervalID:uint variame means, where else i have to use this?

Comment: is `setTimeout` suitable? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html

Comment: I dont know how to use it or it doesnt work, even there is example

Comment: Having a hard time understanding your question.  What event triggers your `time` method that's shown?

Comment: you need to import `flash.utils.setTimeout;`

Comment: intervalID is an id for the timeout, which can be used to cancel the timeout if you wanted

Comment: It does not give errors, but doesent go to that function

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways you could track the time and run a function.

-1.   `flash.utils.setTimeout`
you pass in a function to call and how many milliseconds to wait before calling it.   `setTimeout(myFunction,1000); //call myFunction in 1 second`.

-2.  `flash.utils.Timer`. (or `flash.utils.setInterval`)

The `Timer` class dispatches an event at a set interval either indefinitely or a set amount of times.   This would be good to use if you had something visual that counts while you wait.

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000,10); //this creates a timer that will fire a total of 10 times, once every second
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,tickHandler); //listen for the tick
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerComplete) //TimerEvent is found in the flash.events package
timer.start(); //start the timer.  you can also pause/stop the timer if necessary, or reset it (which stops it and puts the count back to 0)
function tickHandler(e:Event):void {
    //another second has passed, do something
    myTextField.text = timer.currentCount + " seconds have passed";
}

function timerComplete(e:Event):void {
    //timer is done, do something
}
```

-3.  `EnterFrame` Handler.

You can run a function every frame, and track the time passed.  This is only good to do if you need to respond every frame to the time passed.

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);
var startTime:Number = flash.utils.getTimer();
function enterFrame(e:Event):void {
    myTextField.text = (flash.utils.getTimer() - startTime) + " miliseconds have passed";
    if(flash.utils.getTimer() - startTime > 60000){
        //a minute has passed, do something and stop listening
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);
    }
}
```